# Inform7: How do I make Inform7 display text only once when you enter a room but display every time you enter that room

Tags: inform7

I would like to know if you can have Inform7 display something like `say "Welcome to the room!".`
only once when you enter that room. All preceding commands you type will not re-trigger this message but if you leave and re-enter the room it will display again.

The idea is that I have a person in the room who I want to have some greeting text.
Also if possible can I make their text print out after anything else that may be printed in the room?

Comment: Can't you just include that in the room's description?

Comment: @curiousdannii Including it in the room's description would cause it to be repeated in response to "look".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can record whether an actor has just arrived in a room using a [new either/or property](http://inform7.com/book/WI_4_7.html) ("a new arrival" in this example) - set it in an [after rule](http://inform7.com/book/WI_7_5.html) for the "going" action, and clear it in a general [every turn](http://inform7.com/book/WI_9_5.html) rule. The greeting text can be displayed in another every turn rule - [a more specific one to ensure that it runs before the general one that clears the property](http://inform7.com/book/WI_19_16.html) - restricted to cases where the person saying the greeting ("The Greeter" in this example) is both in the correct room ("The Greeting Room" in this example) and able to see a person who is a new arrival:

```
A person can be a new arrival.
A person is usually not a new arrival.

After going:
    now the actor is a new arrival;
    continue the action.

Every turn when the Greeter is in the Greeting Room and the Greeter can see a new arrival person:
    if the player can see the Greeter:
        say "Welcome to the Greeting Room![line break]".

Every turn:
    repeat with newcomer running through new arrival people:
        now the newcomer is not a new arrival.
```